# Best way to use multiple express processes?

Tags: node.js, express

So I'm running a series of chatbots, which have little websites associated with them. I'm using express and handlebars to do all the thing. I'm using iptables to route all data on port `3000` to port `80`.

However, while the wrapper file works on port `3000`, since the bots are started as child processes, each one has to have a different port. I am using the wrapper to route to the ports, but it's still annoying.

For example, I have `chatbot.example.com` on port `3000`, but since bot #1 is a child process, it's running its webserver on port `3001`.

So I have the wrapper route `chatbot.example.com/bot1` to `chatbot.example.com:3001/bot1` 
But that feels horrendously tacky.

Is there any better way to do this?

Current code example: [snippi](http://snippi.com/s/5bni955).

Comment: Why do you have multiple processes at all?

Comment: Because that's how I run the bots? The bots all share the same core files, but each has a different config file which invokes the core files. I start them as child processes. Is there a better way to do that? I used to run them as separate processes entirely, until I started making them child processes.

Comment: Why don't you just `require()` them into the main process & run them directly?

Comment: Because then I couldn't pass messages from the bots to the wrapper? The wrapper is responsible for rebooting the bots on error, disconnect, or just general mishaps. But I guess I can look into it.

Comment: @DaltonGore could you provide a bit more detailed info about how you create the bots and handle its config during the bootstrap? It seems that the best approach to do this is using a single instance of `http.Server`, and route to each chatbot within its `request` handler. This can be done through [`connect.vhost`](http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/vhost.html), but without more information about the bootstrap process of each bot it seems pretty imposible give a posible solution. Please share a bit of relevant code and your project's structure.

Comment: @laconbass I've updated the original post with a code example.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using the `cluster` module for your setup, rather than manually creating a wrapper and spawning child processes. It's probably more stable than what you have, and should let them all share a port if that's what you're looking to do.

I also wouldn't couple (if it were me) between one process == one chatbot.  Instead, I'd write the app such that any process can respond as any chatbot based on the path params or querystring params, using the regular Express routing stuff.  This way if you can load balance your processes based on actual use; one chatbot that's getting hit a lot might be serviced by 2 or 3 processes, while one that's not getting used at all would not consume extra resources.

UPDATED for sample code
So, it looks to me like you're kinda conflating purposes a tidge. I can't tell from your snippet what exactly each site is supposed to do, other than that it's related to a given chat bot.  I'm guessing here that the purpose of each chatbot's site is to display the activity relative to that chatbot's chatting. Seems to me that you're better off launching the chatbots as one node app (or one per chatbot, either way works), which each log to a db of some kind whatever state you want to track.  MongoDb, CouchDb, some SQL db, doesn't matter.  The web app could then be just a single app that simply reads that DB and filters for a given chatbot based on the path.

Overall, feels like you're trying to get the one app do too much.

Comment: I looked into `cluster` but it doesn't work. each bot has its own unique settings. what chat room to monitor, what account to use, etc. and then connects to its own database. (my clients order my bot to monitor their own chat rooms and do moderator type stuff). And if I can't give a fork the config information, it's kind of useless, isn't it?

Comment: Just to note, [`cluster`](http://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html) is still [`experimental`](http://nodejs.org/api/documentation.html#documentation_stability_index)

Comment: Perhaps I didn't explain it well. I understand that each chatbot has its own settings; what I'm suggesting is that you load that upon request rather than on initialization.  it simplifies your architecture.

Comment: @laconbass Yeah, it is, but it's also in pretty common use by now.

Comment: @Paul Sure it is! I simply commented it to warn possible readers.

BTW the key could be spawning on demand as you mention on the second paragraph, rather than coupling processes to chatbots. Anyway I'm curious about how each bot is bootstraped cause it seems too transcendent to assume that the best approach is spawning processes. If the load is high it's obviously the best way, but in any case the load balancer must run on a single process.

This leads mi crazy mind to think that the OP's problem is about the absence of a balancer/router, rather than its implementation.

Comment: I've updated the orignal post with a watered down code example (the chat bot is several thousand lines long, I tried to cover all the necessary bits)

Answer (score 0):

Express can handle vhosts.  I run 3 sites on the same server with express.vhost() with cluster, and they all listen to the same port.

So, you could do something like chatbot1.site.com, chatbot2.site.com, all with the same app, just different vhosts.

```
// main 'server.js' app
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app
    .use(express.vhost('chatbot1.site.com', require('./chatbot1.js').app ) )
    .use(express.vhost('chatbot2.site.com', require('./chatbot2.js').app ) );

// delay for db connections to start up (just what I do)
setTimeout( function () {
    app.listen(port);
}, 2000);
```

In your 'chatbot#.js' file, you'll need to export your app:

```
// chatbot#.js
var app = exports.app = express ();
```

The app in your 'chatbox.js' file will also NOT listen to a port, as the 'server.js' app starts the listening.  You might even be able to get away with using only 1 chatbot.js file, depending on how you store/get it's info.  I think it would be simple enough to copy 'chatbot1.js' and make 'chatbot2.js' with different settings though.  Up to you and how your 'chatbot's get setup.

BTW, this system here also works well with cluster, as you'll only need to wrap the cluster code around the code in the 'server.js' file.

Comment: I've tried this method, and I think it would work, but I'm still only getting one route declaring. (I'm not using subdomains right now, I just set wildcard domains for my domain to point to this server, so perhaps in a few - but right now it's just example.com/chatbot1). And while /chatbot1 is showing, 2 and 3 are not. I have updated with a code example.

Comment: When you call:  boot(configs[i]), you are passing it an object, so when the child process calls: require("./bots/"+process.env.bot+".js"); it's most likely trying to require something that doesn't exist, like './bots/[Object Object].js"

Comment: The bots start, that's not a problem. They all connect to the room just fine. The problem is with the website part of it. In my code, you can see I have 3 bots, `holly`, `fembot`, and `daisy`. All 3 of those bots are running, but as for the domains, only `bot.example.come/holly` will work, while the other 2 return `Cannot GET /daisy` or the like.

Comment: You also might want to simply rethink the whole child process creation per bot.  Node is very fast, so maybe you might want a single 'bot.js' app running that queries your db every minute to check on which chatrooms to monitor.  Then once that is working, wrap that app in the cluster code.

Comment: Post your actual routing code.  The snippet you have included shows a problem with the require I pointed out.  So if you say that part works, but routing doesn't, then show a more detailed snippet of the actual routing.

Comment: In your 'start.js', I don't think you can do it like this:   web.use(express.vhost("site.example.com",require("./site.js")));
web.listen(3000);  You will constantly be trying to listen to the same port every time you spawn a child.  So while your first child will work, the others will most likely error out.

Comment: The bots are on constantly, saving users, etc. I don't think I can have just one master bot. That's well out of my coding experience. And that *is* my actual routing code. I only changed /someroute from what it actually was, like say /rules.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44008/discussion-between-dalton-gore-and-chris)